# Issue with Type Error 1009 Null object reference gameLoop()

Tags: flash, object, null, adobe

I'm having an issue with my flash code. I'm making a simple ball drop game and I keep getting this error

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at balldrop_fla::MainTimeline/gameLoop()[balldrop_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:46]

It seems to be talking about line 46 which is " ball.y += 5;"

Here is my code:

```
 import flash.display.DisplayObject;
 import flash.geom.Rectangle;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.display.MovieClip;


var points:Array = new Array(10,20,30,40,-50)
var ball:DisplayObject;
var randBall:Number;
var score:Number=0;
var rect:Rectangle=new Rectangle(0+(basket_mc.width/2), basket_mc.y,stage.stageWidth-  basket_mc.width, 0);
basket_mc.startDrag(true, rect);

basket_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

function makeBall():void
{
randBall=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

switch(randBall)
{
    case 0:
        ball=addChild(new ball0_mc());
    break;
    case 1:
        ball=addChild(new ball1_mc());
    break;
    case 2:
        ball=addChild(new ball2_mc());
    break;
    case 3:
        ball=addChild(new ball3_mc());
    break;
    case 4:
        ball=addChild(new ball4_mc());
    break;
}
ball.x=Math.floor(Math.random()*stage.stageWidth-ball.width);
ball.y=-60;
}

function gameLoop(evt:Event):void
 {
score_txt.text=score.toString();
ball.y += 5;

if(ball.y>stage.stageHeight + ball.height)
{
    removeChild(ball);
    makeBall();
}
if(ball.hitTestObject(basket_mc))
{
    score += points[randBall];
    removeChild(ball);
    makeBall();
}
 }

makeBall();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing I see is that the listener of ENTER_FRAME is probably called before you instatiate the ball with makeBall(). I would add the listener for ENTER_FRAME after makeBall.

Answer (score 0):

You must try to add

```
stop();
```

at the end of script. Then timeline ends and start playing from beginning, flash recreates all objects at scene and your ball becomes null.

And do you sure that after

randBall=Math.floor(Math.random()*5);

randBall will, at example, 0 instead 0.000000001? Better method here is make randBall's type int instead of Number.